# How can I get mobile number automatically to android app?

Tags: android, mobile, whatsapp

I am new to stack overflow and building apps but i need to learn it. So, please answer and  correct me if anything is wrong.
I am building an android app in which I consider mobile number as his unique id just like Whatsapp.

So can anyone please tell me how to get users number directly into my database when he install this android app?

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mNumber = tManager.getLine1Number();
```

In AndroidManifest.xml, give the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using 
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mNumber = tManager.getLine1Number();

we got mobile number but right now this api depricated. And we can not get mobile number. But you can get sim serial number and it is also unique.